# Using a Variable in Python String

Tags: python, string, python-2.7, variables

I'm not sure how to word the question, and I'm not finding anything in searches.

I have a variable, and want to pass it into `f.open()` as the name of the file to open.
The goal is to type a file name into foo, then it clears the files.

```
foo = str(raw_input('enter a filename '))
bar = foo   
f = open('foo', 'w')
f.write("")
f.close()
```

I've tried using open(foo, 'w') and replacing it with 'bar', but neither  seems to work. Any suggestions?

Comment: What does it mean "doesn't seems to work"? What exactly happens? It should work

Comment: Also, `str` is unnecessary when you get `raw_input`

Comment: Replace 'foo' with foo

Comment: It would run, but instead of clearing the file it would make a new file named "foo". Removing the quotes got it to work

Comment: The line `f.write("")` can be removed. You can even write `open(foo, 'w').close()`.

Comment: @Eric sounds good thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`f = open(bar, 'w')`

Just pass the variable name (without quotes of course).

Additionally, you don't need the line `bar = foo`. You are already storing the filename as `foo` with your first line.

So... if you remove `bar = foo` it would be `f = open(foo, 'w')`

Comment: Don't know how i missed that. Must have been doing it wrong when i tried earlier. Thanks :)

Answer (score 2):

Remove the `''` from `'foo'`:

```
f = open('foo', 'w')
```

Like this:

```
f = open(foo, 'w')
```

`'foo'` is a literal string and `foo` is a variable name that holds the file name the user entered.